# To convert from avi file to mp4 file by ffmpeg command in php

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, mime

The ffmpeg command in php below creates mp4 file from avi file without deleting the original avi file meaning that,for example, 
there are two files, 1221222.avi and 1221222.mp4 exist in the directry after all.

('for i in /xxxxx/xxxxxx/*.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -frames:v 1 "/xxxxx/xxxxxx/$(basename "$i" .avi).mp4"; done')

I'd like to delete this 1221222.avi file right after the command created 1221222.mp4 file.

Is there any command that converts the file from avi to mp4 by replacing it? Or do I have to add delete command after the command above?

I would appreciate if anyone could help me out for the command.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Even though the php script below can upload avi file from local drive to application I'm currently developping, the avi will not be played at html.
So, I'm trying to convert from the avi file to mp4 file which is working fine by using ffmpeg command in php. This ffmpeg command creates mp4, but the html still do not play it. Is it because the original avi file still exists in the directory?

```
//php
case "video/x-msvideo":

if($header){
    header("Content-Type: video/x-msvideo");

 $dst_im = copy($path, $dst_file);
 return "";
 }else{ 

 $dst_file = $dst_file . ".avi";
 shell_exec('for i in  /xxxxxx/xxxxxx/*.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$i" - frames:v 1 "/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/$(basename "$i"  .avi).mp4"; done');      

 $dst_im = copy($path, $dst_file);
 }
 unlink($dst_im);
 break; 


//html
<video width="500"  height="250"  id="bgvid" poster="video.jpg"    controls="controls" preload="auto" autoplay>
<source type="video/mp4" src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such operation, you can just append a bash command like

`rm filename.mp4`

to the script or you remove the file through php with

```
unlink($filepath);
```

Comment: BlackNetworkBit Sorry for confusion. I added more on top why I am doing this. Could you tell me what I should do with this situation?

Comment: Is the mp4 file accessable from the Server, what happens if you request the Video directly ? Under which Browser are you developing ?

Comment: Thanks, BlackNetworkBit, The newly created mp4 from avi is played at html after I moved from the server to  the local and then uploaded to the application again. So it should be played if I request the mp4 directly from html.

Comment: I tried this unlink('/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/*.avi'); right under shell_exec, but it will not delete avi file at all. For rm filename.mp4, I still can not figure out how to use it. Could you show me how to use it?

Comment: Then pleas show your mp4 upload code. Who is the owner of the mp4 file ? what does ls -a says ?

Comment: BlackNetworkBit, Even though I still have some issue to work on to make the front end html playing, shell_exec('rm /xxxx/*.avi'); deletes avi file from directory leaving only the newly created mp4 file from avi file in the directory which I needed. Thanks a lot.